# Call variables created in JVM after JVM is closed in JPype

Tags: jpype

I create a hashmap in JVM and want to access it after jpype.shutdownJVM, how can I do that?

I know dict works as hashmap in python, I tried:

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(),"-Djava.class.path=%s" % classpath)
hashmap = jpype.java.util.HashMap()
...#insert pairs
jpype.shutdownJVM()
...
hashmap["key"]  this doesnot work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The key access will get mapped to java calls. Since you've shut down the jvm this won't work.

You have to create a new python dictionary from the Java HashMap first. Make sure the values are no complex Java objects and can get [translated automatically](http://jpype.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#type-conversion).

```
import jpype
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())
hashmap = jpype.java.util.HashMap()
# insert pairs
hashmap.put("foo", "bar")
# normally newmap = dict(hashmap) should work but jpype
# doesn't seem to support this...
newmap = {}
for i in hashmap:
    # you might have to map more complex keys or values to python objects
    # before putting them into newmap
    newmap[i] = hashmap[i]
jpype.shutdownJVM()
print newmap["foo"]
```